# Stop DropDownList In Asp.net webforms from refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

I have a normal dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="kindofser" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        Height="21px" Width="166px" 
        onselectedindexchanged="kindofser_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>שרתי משחק</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">rgrgr</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">rgreger</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Everytime I change my option, a SelectedIndexChanged event happens, but the page is refreshed. Can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `AutoPostBack` property from the markup.

`AutoPostBack` gets or sets a value that indicates whether an automatic postback to the server occurs when the selected index has been changed in a `DropDownList`. The default value of this `DropDownList.AutoPostBack` is *false*.

If you need to update a part of your page's data, you could use [Partial Page Updates with ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax).

Comment: if you put auto post back to false, when you change your select its not doing the " protected void XX_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  , so , what cani do ?

Comment: the event dont happnd.. if i put "autopostback" its not doing anything. just nothing.. when will it happnd?

Comment: The value of the drop down list will be bound when the form is submitted by some other action, like a pressing a button.

Comment: @Alon M: The `DropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged` event will be fired at the first post back of the page to the server. That may happen if you clicked a button for example. Setting the `DropDownList.AutoPostBack` to _true_ does not fire the mentioned event. It just posts back the page to the server.

Comment: @Alon M: [Partial Page Updates](http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax) will solve your problem then.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

In your case you need to use updatepanel because you are using "onselectedindexchanged" event. so here the code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

<asp:DropDownList ID="kindofser" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        Height="21px" Width="166px" 
        onselectedindexchanged="kindofser_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>שרתי משחק</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">rgrgr</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">rgreger</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>


</ContentTemplate>  
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Regards

Ali Muhammad**

Answer (score 1):

Set `AutoPostBack="False"` instead of true.